# Issue in For loop in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am new to `for` loops in R. I am writing a code like this:

```
attr <- names(training_data)    
attach(training_data)
for(i in 1:500) {
  temp_var = attr[i]
}
```

The value of `attr[1]` is `abcd`.

when i try displaying the values of `temp_var` I should get a `abcd`, however I am getting a `"abcd"`. With quotes:

```
> print(attr[1])
"abcd"
```

How can I get it like the below (without quotes):

```
> print(attr[1])
abcd
```

Basically, I want to pass the attribute names of table in run time and assign the values of the vector to a temp variable. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a simple R programming question with no Data Science and would do MUCH better on stackoverflow.stackexchange.com

Comment: I apologize sincerely for posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a Char data type, you are getting "" around your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't- R displays char type variables with "" around it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go with

```
temp <- as.factor(temp_var[1])
print(temp_var[1])
```

which will print

```
[1] abcd
Levels: abcd
```

But converting to a factor comes with other consequences. Why do you want it without the apostrophe? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have slightly improved the code now. If you see i want to pass all the values in attr[1] to temp_var. If i have quotes, then R assigns nothing but the quoted string abcd. If no quotes, then R will assign the values in the vector

Comment: I want to pass the attribute names of table in run time and assign the values of the vector to a temp variable. How can i achieve this?